# how to convert peerID into UDID?

Tags: iphone, gamekit, udid

I want to convert the peerID into UDID, instead of name of iphone, how can I do it?

Comment: PeerID is randomly generated number by iOS, when some devices is in range of bluetooth....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using `GKSession`'s peer id, if you are, try - `(NSString *)displayNameForPeer:(NSString *)peerID` ?

Comment: it will return you the name of the iphone, not the UDID yar

Comment: Oh whoops, misread your question :), was thinking you wanted to display a human readable value to the user. Don't think you can get a udid for a different phone that way. If you're just looking for the current phone's user id, you could use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`

Comment: but it will give you UDID, but not the UDID of peerID, peerID can be any random generated number from iphone iOS

Answer (score 0):

Your cannot. peerID identifies a device only during one connected GKSession. Once you reconnect or start a new GKSession, the same device gets a different peerID.